# ActiveRecord select one attribute from class

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a SQL query that i want to write using ActiveRecord query interface, but i haven't been able to guess what alias ActiveRecord will give to that table. Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT P2.NUM_DOCUMENTO FROM
SCHEMA1.PESSOA_CPBS PC
INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.PESSOA P ON(PC.PESSOA = P.ID_PESSOA)
INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL R ON(R.PESSOA = P.ID_PESSOA)
INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.PESSOA P2 ON(R.REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL = P2.ID_PESSOA)
WHERE PC.INSCRICAO = ?
```

And here's the same query written in Ruby(ActiveRecord):

```
Pessoa::PessoaCPBS.joins(pessoa: [representantes: :representante])
                  .select('representante.num_documento')
                  .where('inscricao = :inscricao', inscricao: ?)
```

ActiveRecord generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
  representante.num_documento 
FROM 
  "SCHEMA1"."PESSOA_CPBS" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA" ON "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA"."ID_PESSOA" = "SCHEMA1"."PESSOA_CPBS"."PESSOA" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL" ON "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL"."PESSOA" = "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA"."ID_PESSOA" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA" "REPRESENTANTE_GRPFOR_REPRESENT" ON "REPRESENTANTE_GRPFOR_REPRESENT"."ID_PESSOA" = "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL" 
WHERE (inscricao = ?)
```

And i get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "REPRESENTANTE"."NUM_DOCUMENTO": invalid identifier
```

Here's the query that i want ActiveRecord to spit out:

```
SELECT 
  "REPRESENTANTE_GRPFOR_REPRESENT"."NUM_DOCUMENTO"
FROM 
  "SCHEMA1"."PESSOA_CPBS" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA" ON "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA"."ID_PESSOA" = "SCHEMA1"."PESSOA_CPBS"."PESSOA" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL" ON "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL"."PESSOA" = "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA"."ID_PESSOA" 
  INNER JOIN "SCHEMA2"."PESSOA" "REPRESENTANTE_GRPFOR_REPRESENT" ON "REPRESENTANTE_GRPFOR_REPRESENT"."ID_PESSOA" = "SCHEMA2"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL"."REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL" 
WHERE (inscricao = ?)
```

How can i guess the alias that the table will get????

Answer (score 1):

You can change into:

```
Pessoa::PessoaCPBS.select('representate_grpfor_represent.num_documento')
   .joins(pessoa: [representantes: :representante])
   .where('inscricao = ?', "put-your-search-string-here")
```

Add `joins` alias in `select` table you can do this:

```
Pessoa::PessoaCPBS.select('P2.num_documento')
   .joins("AS PC INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.PESSOA P ON(PC.PESSOA = P.ID_PESSOA) INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL R ON(R.PESSOA = P.ID_PESSOA) INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.PESSOA P2 ON (R.REPRESENTANTE_LEGAL = P2.ID_PESSOA)")
   .where('PC.inscricao = ?', "put-your-search-string-here")
```

You can fix into your necessary because the your first query and last query is different especially in last `INNER JOIN`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Muhamad, i know this would solve my problem, but there's got to be a way that a can guess which alias AC will give to a given table! This way i will always have to run a query, look a the sql log, than change my query. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check it and change it when need to fix it. I hope it works.

Comment: Muhamad, do you think there's a way to do this without using SQL?